# How to visible full item when click on item in reyclerview android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-listview, android-adapter

Hey I am working in android. I have list in horizontal form. I want to do, If my view is half visible in device and if clicked, then me recylerview scroll that item, i.e. it will visible it fully. So How Can I do in my recyclerview. Can someone Suggest me how can I achieved this through recyclerview in android.

The image in which view is not selected and you can see last item is half visible.

[image]

The image when view is clicked but item is half visible in device.

[image]

I want to fully visible that item, if I clicked on the view like below image. I can't show animation becuase I didn't achieve yet. Hope you guys understand what I want. Thanks

[image]

Comment: what about using `recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);` on every click item?

Comment: @MoustafaEL-Saghier but how to we know we item is not fully visible then I want to visible that item only.

Comment: If the item is already fully visible, `smoothScrollToPosition` won't do anything, so you can just call it from your click listener without checking anything.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I suggested that to guarantee it'll be scroll always, but what you said mean it'll scroll on its own when clicking?

Comment: @MoustafaEL-Saghier I don’t understand what you’re asking.

Comment: I mean the item will be fully visible or not after click?

Comment: Hey @Tenfour04 can you look this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71380874/11560810)